# C++11: "narrowing conversion inside { }" with modulus

Tags: c++, c++11, narrowing

I try to compile the following code with `gcc` and `C++11` enabled:

```
unsigned int id = 100;
unsigned char array[] = { id % 3, id % 5 };
```

I get these warnings:

> narrowing conversion of ‘(id % 3u)’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘unsigned char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

[see demo online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c7c2108e5e1494)

Is there a way to help the compiler find out that the result of **id % 3** fits into an **unsigned char**?

Comment: [`static_cast<unsigned char>(id % 3)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbad5bda6bc9c1d7) ?

Comment: Can't you store the result in an array of ints? What will you use it for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this specific case making `id` *const* or [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) will fix the problem:

```
constexpr unsigned int id = 100;
```

since there is an exception for the case where you have a *constant expression* whose result after conversion will fit into the target type.

In the more general case you may also use [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) to cast the result to unsigned char:

```
{ static_cast<unsigned char>( id % 3), static_cast<unsigned char>( id % 5) }
  ^^^^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We can find he exception for *constant expressions* and narrowing conversions in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `8.5.4` *List-initialization* which says:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion

and include the following bullet (*emphasis mine*):

> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except
>     where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral
>     promotions will fit into the target type**.

Note, the wording changed from the original draft C++11 standard to what I quote above due to [defect report 1449](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3540.html#1449).

Answer (score 3):

It is a quirk of C++ that almost all mathematical operations convert their arguments to `int`.

Here is a sketch of a non-widening `%mod%` operator:

```
template<class T, class U,class=void> struct smallest{using type=T;};
template<class T, class U>
struct smallest<T,U,std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T)>sizeof(U))>>{using type=U;};
template<class T,class U>using smallest_t=typename smallest<T,U>::type;

constexpr struct mod_t {} mod;
template<class LHS>struct half_mod { LHS lhs; };
template<class LHS>
constexpr half_mod<std::decay_t<LHS>> operator%( LHS&& lhs, mod_t ) { return {std::forward<LHS>(lhs)}; }
template<class LHS, class RHS>
constexpr smallest_t<LHS, std::decay_t<RHS>> operator%( half_mod<LHS>&& lhs, RHS&& rhs ) {
  return std::move(lhs.lhs) % std::forward<RHS>(rhs);
}
```

The result of a mod b should be the smallest of the two types, as it cannot be larger.  Possibly some work should be done for signed/unsigned, but I'll punt and take the first.

So `id %mod% 3` ends up being `char`.

Comment: I guess there is a small mistake: `operator%( LHS&& lhs, mod )` needs to be `operator%( LHS&& lhs, mod_t )`. Aside from that: This only works for me if I cast to char: `id %mod% (char) 3`, otherwise the **3** is also interpreted as a `int` by the compiler. Any way around that?

Comment: @m.s. bah, I figured that the constant was a `char` not an `int`.  As horrible as it is, `'\3'` is the character constant `3`.  :/  Probably your best bet is `constexpr` on the `id` really, if it is really a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
unsigned char array[] = {
    static_cast<unsigned char>(id % 3),
    static_cast<unsigned char>(id % 5)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As `id` is an `unsigned int`, the type of `id % 3` will also be an `unsigned int`.

Your compiler is helpfully warning you that `unsigned char` (which is 8 bits by the standard), *might* be too small to receive the `unsigned int` (which is at least 16 bits by the standard).

Of course you know better in this particular instance. Use `static_cast<unsigned char>(id % ...)` to tell the compiler that the narrowing conversion is safe.