# Create array of chars avoiding narrowing

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, narrowing

I am writing a unit test checking some binary data against an expected array. The expected array in question is just some series of bytes, doesn't matter specifically:

```
char expected[] = {0x42, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef};
```

This compiled fine in C++, but with C++11 this issues a warning on narrowing conversion. I compile with `-Werror` because warnings matter, so that line does not compile for me. As far as I'm aware, there's no literal suffix for char, so it seems I'd have to do:

```
char expected[] = {static_cast<char>(0x42), static_cast<char>(0xde), ... };
```

That seems pretty unwieldy to me. Is there a better way to construct this character array? (Outside of either removing `-Werror` or adding `-Wno-narrowing`).

Comment: The bytes should be declared as `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: the signess of char is implementation specific. If you get this error means that those values don't fit in a char meaning the char is signed on your platform. Regardless, for compatibility you should declare `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` as specified before for variables meant to hold byte values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So C++11 has an exception for *integer* types and *unscoped enums* for [constant expressions that fit after promtion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26974911/1708801) in the target type, the draft C++11 standard section `8.5.4` *[dcl.init.list]* says:

> from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type
>   that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except
>   where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral
>   promotions will fit into the target type.

The problem here is that some of the values do not fit into `char` if you use `unsigned char` instead it should work.

`clang` is a little more helpful in that it warns which specific elements generate the warning and in this case it does not warn for `0x42` but does for the rest, for example:

```
error: constant expression evaluates to 222 which cannot be narrowed to type 'char' [-Wc++11-narrowing]
char expected[] = {0x42, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef};
                         ^~~~
```