# Narrowing conversion from `int` (constant expression) to `unsigned int` - MSVC vs gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer

```
constexpr int i = 100;
struct F { F(unsigned int){} };
int main() { F{i}; }
```

The snippet above:

- Compiles *with no warnings* on `g++ 7` with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.
- Compiles *with no warnings* on `clang++ 4` with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.
- Fails to compile on `MSVC 2017`:

  > conversion from 'const int' to 'unsigned int' requires a narrowing conversion

**Q:** is MSVC wrong here?

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/NIJfWp)

---

```
int i = 100;
struct F { F(unsigned int){} };
int main() { F{i}; }
```

- Compiles **with warnings** on `g++ 7` with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`:

  > narrowing conversion of 'i' from 'int' to 'unsigned int'
- Fails to compile `clang++ 4` with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`:

  > non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'unsigned int' in initializer list
- Fails to compile on `MSVC 2017`:

  > conversion from 'const int' to 'unsigned int' requires a narrowing conversion

**Q:** is g++ wrong here? *(i.e. should it produce an hard error?)*

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/Gw7JBY)

Comment: Most times the standard just says _"a diagnostic"_ which covers both warning and errors.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I see, thanks. I assume that MSVC is wrong in the first snippet then? And according to Richard, I assume that g++ and clang++ are compliant in both snippets.

Comment: With GCC, to turn standard-mandated diagnostics into an error, but only the standard-mandated ones, use `-pedantic-errors`, though as mentioned warnings are sufficient to meet the standard's requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is never a requirement that any C++ program produce a hard error.  There are requirements to print diagnostics.  The form of the diagnostic is unspecified by the standard: an old joke is that printing out a single space satisifies the diagnostic requirements of the standard.  That would be a quality of implementation issue.

There are ill-formed programs upon which the standard places no restrictions on their behavior, and sometimes a mandatory diagnostic.

There are cases where a program is ill-formed and a diagnostic is required.  One way to handle that is to produce a message saying it is an error, then do not generate any binary to run.  Another way is to produce a message saying it is a warning, then produce a binary that can be run.

So, g++ is not wrong under the standard for merely printing out a warning.

The resulting program is technically all undefined behavior; g++ could format your hard drive when it runs without violating the standard.  That would be considered a quality of implementation issue.

[Shafik's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26974911/1774667) covers the first question.  `i` is  constant expression and its value fits the target type; there should be no warning or error about the narrowing conversion.

The C++ standard does not defend you against hostile compilers.

Reportedly, `-pedantic-errors` can be passed to g++ to have it generate hard errors instead of warnings when the standard mandates the resulting program would be ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks, clarified all my doubts. I'll report this to the MSVC tracker if it's not already there.

Comment: It would be helpful if the Standard would clarify that failure to prohibit a behavior does not mean that a compiler that behaves in that fashion should not be viewed as grossly inferior to one that behaves in some other fashion, all else being equal.  It is reasonable for the Standard not to *require* that an implementation accept program #2, and allow for implementations to indicate errors via any means they see fit, but that doesn't mean that a quality implementation given #2 shouldn't behave in constrained fashion.

Comment: @supercat That is a quality of implementation issue.  The fact that the compiler does not violate the standard by doing anything is a joke, as is the fact that `" "` is a valid diagnostic message.  Trying to enforce that kind of stuff is stupid when *there is no problem*, no actual "real" compiler does stupid evil stuff like that on purpose.

Comment: @Yakk: There are a couple problems: 1. It has become fashionable for compiler to behave in ways that in years past would have been recognized as stupid; 2. A good standard should be able to make solid guarantees, and the present standard really can't.  For example, there should be defined sets of implementations ("Safely Conforming") and programs ("Selectively Conforming") such that feeding any program in the latter group to any compiler in the former would, at worst, choose in Unspecified Fashion from among a defined set of Implementation-Defined behaviors.

Comment: @Yakk: For an implementation to qualify as Safely-Conforming, for example, it would have to either specify the ways in which it might behave if a stack overflow occurs, or provide means by which it could statically verify that stack overflows could not occur when given a Selectively-Conforming program (adding a stack-check intrinsic to the language would make support for such a guarantee practical even for programs that use function pointers and recursion).  Not all implementations could support such guarantees, but it would be practical to make the set of tasks that could be done by...

Comment: ...Selectively Conforming programs vastly larger than the set of tasks that can be done by Strictly Conforming programs.  Whether an implementation successfully runs a program or fails with an Implementation-Defined error message can be sensibly regarded as a QofI issue.  Whether an implementation correctly runs a program or may behave in arbitrary fashion should not be regarded as a QofI issue.  A standard can only have meaning if it actually imposes some constraints, but there is no category of useful programs for which the Standard would constrain conforming implementations' behavior.