# Does C++ allow any integer literal to be implicitly converted to a short int?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, type-conversion, compiler-warnings, literals

```
int main()
{
    short n1 = 8ll; // no warning

    // warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from '__int64' to 'short'
    // warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value
    short n2 = 88888ll;
}
```

My compiler is Visual Studio 2017.

According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value
>   can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base
>   and which integer-suffix was used.

The integer literal with suffix `ll` should be of `long long int`; so `short n1 = 8ll` should trigger a warning like `short n2 = 88888ll` does.

**Does C++ allow any integer literal to be implicitly converted to a `short int` if it is small enough?**

Comment: " should trigger a warning " - compilers are pretty free when it comes to warnings. They may give warnings when the Standard says a diagnostic is required, but they may also give them for situations where the Standard is silent. And a compiler can be smart about it. It knows its own limits, so it can give warnings for `88888LL` and not for `8LL`.

Comment: You can use braces to disable implicit conversion, e.g. `short n2 = { 88888LL };` (This feature was added in C++11)

Comment: @M.M: The braced initializer syntax disables **narrowing** conversions.  Implicit widening conversions still happen.

Comment: @M.M but there is an exception [for constant expressions whose results fits the target type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26974911/1708801) so this will not help in the first case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard allows the implicit conversion between any two integer types, regardless of their values.

The compiler warnings are unrelated to the code being legal; the compiler just warns you when your code probably does not do what you wanted it to.

In your specific case, `n1` would be 8 and `n2` would have an implementation defined value. Both assignments are legal C++, but the latter is probably not what you intended.

---

Relevant standardese:

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped
>   enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>   If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s
>   complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there
>   is no truncation). — end note ]
>   If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>   bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

4.7/1-3 in N4141

Answer (score 4):

Yes, integers can be converted implicitly. These are the rules from the C++ standard draft N4296:

> **4.7 Integral conversions**
>   <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be
>   converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>   <sup>2</sup> If the destination type
>   is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer
>   congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of
>   bits used to represent the unsigned type).
>   [ *Note:* In a two’s
>   complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is
>   no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). *—end note* ]
>   <sup>3</sup> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is
>   implementation-defined.
>   <sup>4</sup> If the destination type is bool, see 4.12.
>   If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
>   the value true is converted to one.
>   <sup>5</sup> The conversions allowed as
>   integral promotions are excluded from the set of integral conversions.