# Why does this code to initialize a string to a single character call the initializer_list constructor?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

I was recently working on a C++ project and came across an edge case with the string constructors that I can't fully understand. The relevant code (which [you can run here](https://ideone.com/sA1Lze)) is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string directParens(1, '*');
    string directBraces{1, '*'};
    string indirectBraces = {1, '*'};

    cout << directParens.size() << endl;   // 1
    cout << directBraces.size() << endl;   // 2
    cout << indirectBraces.size() << endl; // 2
    return 0;
}
```

The brace-initialized versions of the strings end up having two characters in them, namely, a `char` with numeric value 1 followed by a star.

I don't understand why the brace-initialized versions of the string invoke the `initializer_list` constructor rather than the constructor taking in a size and a character. The `initializer_list` constructor has this signature:

```
basic_string(std::initializer_list<CharT> init, 
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Given that `string` is an alias for `basic_string` char, the specific signature would be

```
string(std::initializer_list<char> init, 
       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

How is the initializer `{1, '*'}`, which contains elements both of type `int` and of type `char`, matching this constructor? I was under the impression that all literals in an `std::initializer_list` must have the same type - is that incorrect?

Comment: Note, there is an exception for narrowing conversions [for constant expression whose result after conversion will fit into the target type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26974911/1708801)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How is the initializer {1, '*'}, which contains elements both of type int and of type char, matching this constructor?

Because both the literal `1` and the character `'*'` are convertible to `char` without using a narrowing conversion. Therefore, they are eligible to call the `initializer_list<char>` constructor. And `initializer_list` constructors *always* have priority when using list initialization. If it is possible to call the `initializer_list` constructor from the parameters, then it will.

Never use braced-init-lists with containers *unless* you intend the elements in the list to be *elements* of the container. If you intend them to be constructor parameters, then use a constructor.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So a brace initializer will be interpreted as an initializer_list if all elements can be converted to the underlying type without narrowing conversions. To confirm, would that mean that { 3, 3.0 } could be interpreted as an initializer_list<double>, but not an initializer_list<int>? And {INT_MAX, '*'} could be an initializer_list<char>?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Well, the `{INT_MAX, '*'}` example *can't* be an `initializer_list<char>`, since `INT_MAX` cannot be converted to `char` without a narrowing conversion. But otherwise, you're correct.

Comment: Oh, I thought the narrowing conversion applied to the *type*, not the *value.* That clears things up! Thanks!

Comment: Overload resolution doesn't care about whether a conversion is narrowing. It will still pick the `initializer_list` constructor, then that results in an ill-formed program.

Comment: @T.C.: Wow, you've managed to make me hate list initialization *even more*.

Comment: *"Never use braced-init-lists with containers unless you intend the elements in the list to be elements of the container. If you intend them to be constructor parameters, then use a constructor."* - I think this should be in bold. ...Nonetheless, +1 for this nugget.