# C++ - Invalid narrowing conversion from "int" to "unsigned char"

Tags: c++

I am trying to to create a vector that contains a static_cast of an interger value as so:

```
int code = 52;
std::vector<uint8_t> data1 = { 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 224 + static_cast<uint8_t>(code / 16), static_cast<uint8_t>(code % 16) };
```

However I am hitting the error:

```
Invalid narrowing conversion from "int" to "unsigned char"
```

Can anyone advise why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Make it `static_cast<uint8_t>(224 + code / 16)` You are adding `uint8_t` to an `int` - the result is of type `int`.

Comment: Alternative you can make `code` a `constexpr` see [C++11: “narrowing conversion inside { }” with modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26974775/1708801) for explanation

Answer (score 0):

You shall use static_cast to do it.
Something like,

```
static_cast<uint8_t>(224 + code / 16)
```