# Why gcc warns about narrowing conversion only for uniform initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, compiler-warnings, uniform-initialization

I am trying to convert `long` type variable to `int` type variable with [`uniform initialization`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and without it. But I get compiler warning only with uniform initialization. Why is that? Why does not `gcc` warn in both cases? I have tried with `clang` also and got similar results.

**This is the code**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long l = 1;
    int i1 = l;
    int i2 = { l };

    std::cout << i1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << i2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**And the only one warning I get**

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra 1.cpp
1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
1.cpp:6:16: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘l’ from ‘long int’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
   int i2 = { l };
```

Comment: Because that's how the language is specified to work?

Comment: It is just one of the language pitfalls preserved for backwards compatibility.

Comment: The compiler is (almost) never obligated to warn. Consider warnings as a helping hand, but don't rely on the compiler always warning about questionable constructs or wrong code. In the end it is your responsibility to know the language rules and write correct code. The compiler just tries to help out when it can (usually). As for narrowing conversions; those are only not permitted when using the "{}" syntax.

Comment: use `-Wconversion` get more conversion warnings.

Comment: With my compiler, I have warnings turned on, and I'm seeing warnings for both the first and second cases, and in addition an error for the second case.  Do you have warnings enabled for you compiler?

Comment: @JesperJuhl to be more precise: The compiler is (almost) always obliged to issue a diagnostic message when the program is ill-formed (such as in the case of the third initialisation of the example). However, if the compiler chooses to refuse to compile the ill-formed program (as it is allowed to, but not obliged), the diagnostic message is colloquially categorised as an error, rather than a warning. Compilers are not obliged to warn about well-formed code, such as the first two initialisations.

Comment: @Eljay, I have enabled warnings with `-Wall -Wextra`, but I did't use `-Wconversion` which is not included neither into `-Wall` nor `-Wextra` (+1 for geza).

Comment: Warning for the unwary l (L) looks like 1 (one). The third case uses l (L), which is not a const and has incompatible range, while the first 2 case uses 1 (one), which is a const. The second case should also give a warning as it uses l (L), but one that is often disabled, as direct assignment between signed and unsigned int types is commonplace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the standard says, [narrowing conversions limit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) is specified only for list initialization (since C++11).

> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
>   prohibiting the following:
>
> - conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type
> - conversion from a long double to double or to float and conversion from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression
>     and overflow does not occur
> - conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value can be stored
>     exactly in the target type
> - conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, except where source
>     is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the
>     target type

For the other initialization methods (using parentheses or equal sign), narrowing conversions limit rule is not applied (added); because that might break much legacy code.

Comment: Note you have an [exception for constant expressions that whose result fit into the target type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26974911/1708801)

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two is that narrowing conversions are not allowed in a list initialization. In other forms of initialization they are allowed.

The thing that often confuses people here is that when something is not allowed it doesn't mean that the compiler must refuse to compile the code. The requirement is that the compiler must "issue a diagnostic", and a warning is a valid form of diagnostic.

So the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic for a narrowing conversion in a list initialization, and that's what you're seeing. Beyond that, as others have said, you can crank up the warning level to get warnings about narrowing conversions in other contexts. But outside of list initialization diagnostics are not required, and they're often more annoying than useful, so not turned on by default.