# Why list initialization disallow narrowing?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know list initialization({} initialization) disallow narrowing, like conversion float to int, but I don't just want know it's like this, can anyone tell me the reason of standard?

Comment: Narrowing (unexpectedly) was a known source of programming errors.  List initialisation is/was new and this change could be made without breaking existing program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why gcc warns about narrowing conversion only for uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497097/why-gcc-warns-about-narrowing-conversion-only-for-uniform-initialization)