# C++ vector size to int conversion warning

Tags: c++

I have just started learning c++, and I found an strange behavior while assigning vector size to int.

When I do like below, Then there is no warning

```
int removeElement(vector<int> &nums)
{
     const int len = nums.size();
}
```

But when I write code like this, then it gives me warning

```
 warning: narrowing conversion of '(& nums)->std::vector<int>::size()'
 from 'std::vector<int>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} to
 'int' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

The erroneous code:

```
int removeElement(vector<int> &nums)
{
     const int len { nums.size() };
}
```

I want to understand, why there is no warning in first case?

Comment: @KamilCuk: I want to understand, why there is no warning in first case?
updated the question as well.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497097/why-gcc-warns-about-narrowing-conversion-only-for-uniform-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497097/why-gcc-warns-about-narrowing-conversion-only-for-uniform-initialization)

Comment: @drescherjm I would call that a duplicate.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Yes, It does.

Comment: Also want to mention that there's lots of memory these days, you might as well just use size_t or use modern c++ and go with auto type.