# Why is a narrowing conversion from int to unsigned int required here only with brace-initialisation?

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct VkExtent2D {
    uint32_t    width;
    uint32_t    height;
} VkExtent2D;





int main()
{

    int a = 3;
    VkExtent2D{ a, a }; // DOESN'T WORK "invalid narrowing conversion from int to unsigned int 
    VkExtent2D( a, a ); // IS FINE 
}
```

I am compiling on Visual Studio with C++20.

Comment: From searching around I find "List initialization does not allow narrowing [(§iso.8.5.4)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.list)" from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/what-are-the-advantages-of-list-initialization-using-curly-braces). Though the standard page itself doesn't seem to offer much direct help.

Comment: Regardless of how you do it, `int` to `unsigned int` is a narrowing conversion. Narrowing conversions are okay when you initialize with parentheses; they're not okay when you initialize with curly braces.

Comment: backwards compatibility.  `()` has always allowed narrowing conversion, to the benefit and downfall of many a programmer.  When C++11 was introduced and brace initialization was expanded into uniform initialization it was decide to not allow narrowing conversions because of the issue they can cause.

Comment: Yes... "universal initialization" is at fault here. https://twitter.com/timur_audio/status/1004017362381795329

Comment: If you have a spare hour here is a great talk about a lot of the initialization issues you'll find in C++: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Comment: @NathanOliver uniform initialization is a disaster in general, one of the thing which was not well thought

Comment: [Why gcc warns about narrowing conversion only for uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497097/why-gcc-warns-about-narrowing-conversion-only-for-uniform-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

Both are *narrowing conversions* in the sense of the standard, because not all values of `int` fit into `uint32_t`, already because of the sign.

However, normally narrowing conversions are simply allowed as explicit as well as implicit conversions. This has always been the case since C (or longer).

Unfortunately a narrowing conversion is usually a defect in the code and therefore it is a problem that these conversions can happen implicitly or even explicitly without some clear indication that the conversion is intended.

With C++11 adding new meaning to initialization with braces, it was decided to make narrowing conversions ill-formed if the initialization uses braces. Except for old aggregate initialization cases this was a non-breaking change and so was more reasonable than e.g. making *all* narrowing conversions in all contexts ill-formed, which would seriously break most non-trivial programs.

This is actually a good reason to generally prefer initialization with braces over parentheses. It is much easier to create a bug or vulnerability if narrowing conversions are not diagnosed, although that diagnosis can also come from a compiler warning or external lint tool as well.

Unfortunately there are also arguments *against* generally preferring initialization with braces, so it isn't that easy. I don't intend to list all pros and cons. There should be sufficient discussion on that topic on this site and elsewhere.